# Does a function assigned to a window property still have access to local variables?

Tags: javascript, flash, window

Question: when declaring a function on window, does the function still have access to the local vars?

```
(function(){
    var foo = "poo"; //local var
    window.bar = function(){
        alert(foo);
    }
})();

bar();
```

I tested this in jsfiddle and it works, however my IDE is suggesting it shouldn't.  Thoughts?  Best practice comments?

http://jsfiddle.net/nRT6B/1/

For reference, I'm declaring the function globally because of a Flash fallback - Flash cannot reference my self-closing function

Comment: Yes. A closure is formed no matter where the function ends up being assigned.

Comment: Well technically according to declaration hierarchy, local stuff can access window stuff but not the other way around because window is higher in the hierarchy. Like in a company every worker knows the ceo but ceo doesnt know/care about workers.  In jsfiddle it might be working because jsfiddle has its own "virtual window" u dont attach it really to the browser its jsfiddle internal.

Comment: @sabof As there really isn't a better answer .. should post that, perhaps with a link to closures in general.

Comment: Perhaps write it like this (from the global scope): `bar = (function(){ var foo = "poo"; return function(){ alert(foo); } })();` to not have a "sneaky" side-effect.

Comment: @Banana Your statement is wrong. As sabof said, the anonymous function creates a closure over the `foo` var, so its value can be accessed and used without any problems in that function. The IDE might be suggesting it won't work maybe because it has a poor or non-existent implementation for closure detection.

Answer (score 1):

your function is not defined in `window`. It is defined in the anonymous wrapper function, and then assigned to a property in window.

Functions have access to any variable that is in the same scope in which they are defined, it does not matter to which object they are assigned, or how many times. A function can be assigned to hundreds of different objects, but that does not change how it works, except if you assign it to a prototype of an object an then call it through an *instance* of an object. But that's just because of the special way in which they are called, making their context (the `this` object) be the current object caller. In fact, this

```
var a = new Array();
a.push(1);
```

is equivalent to

```
var a = new Array();
Array.prototype.push.call(a, 1);
```